# What changes have been made between Gamearth and Hexworld, since the latter is just a rewrite of the former?

Tags: kevin-j-anderson

[Hexworld](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2866220), a.k.a Gamearth.

The game in the book has been renamed to match the rewrite, but there's probably been other changes? What are they, if they exist?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamearth_Trilogy) says "The Gamearth Trilogy was republished as Hexworld, comprising Roll, Play and End, all published in 2021 with some revisions and additional editing, **noted by the author in the foreword of Roll**."  All you need do is find a copy.

Comment: @DoscoJones - Oh, it's not because I'm asking for something I could research myself, were I to shell out... ~30 bucks, but that I'm asking for a list?

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question and similar to ones we've had before

Comment: @DoscoJones - the forward simply notes, almost literally, the new books are a rewrite "_with some revisions and additional editing_", it doesn't note _what_ those revisions were.